# Button under images or on the images *ngFor loop

Tags: css, angular

From *ngFor loop I can populate images but I want to add a button below the image or on the image. I'm not familiar with CSS below is my code.

**Html code**

```
    <div class="container">
              <div *ngFor="let img of imageData">
                <p [hidden]="true">{{img.Id}}</p>
                <img class="original" [alt]="img.Name"
                     src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}"
                     width="350" height="350"/>
                <button type="submit" (click)="deleteImage()" class="btn btn-danger"><i 
                    class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.original {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.container {
    /* position: relative;*/
    text-align: center; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.original {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66% auto;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Image Id</p>
        <img class="original" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" width="350" height="350" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            Remove
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Image Id</p>
        <img class="original" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" width="350" height="350" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            Remove
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For angular with dynamic image your template will be like.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"  *ngFor="let img of imageData">
        <p [hidden]="true">{{img.Id}}</p>
        <img class="original" src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}" width="350" height="350" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            Remove
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. my images are dynamically loading.

Comment: You can use ` src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}"` I have updated the answer